# Tag each API with expected responce when executing assertions

Tags: api, jmeter, response, assertions

is there a way to 'tag' each API in jmeter so that I could specify which response from each API is expected?
For example, if not logged in - some API's give 500 error, and some still give 200. I would like to specify, which API's should give response 500 back (response 200 would be an error), and which still can give 200 (for those APIs response 200 is OK). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. For those API endpoints which should return HTTP Status code 200:

   - Add [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) as a child of the HTTP Request
   - Configure it as follows:

     - Response Field to Test: `Response Code`
     - Pattern Matching Rules: `Equals`
     - Patterns to Test: `200`

       [image: JMeter Response Assertion 200]
2. For those API endpoints which should return HTTP Status code 500:

   - Add Response Assertion as a child of the HTTP Request
   - Configure it as follows:

     - Response Field to Test: `Response Code`
     - Pattern Matching Rules: `Equals`
     - Patterns to Test: `500`
     - **Check `Ignore Status` box**

       [image: JMeter Response Assertion 500]

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) to learn more about JMeter assertions, where to put, when to use, what is the impact, etc.

Comment: Maybe I described my question not clear :) I wanted to know, how IN ADVANCE I could mark (tag) the APIS, for which I should use 200 as positive result and for which 500? I want to make one general assertion to all the API's in my test (probably by using groovy). Many thanks in advance!